# How to feed a column with a join ? (update join)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with financials data for an index named S&P500 (date, ticker, price).

I have another dataframe with (date, ticker, Action).

Action == "IN" when a ticker is added to the index at date

Action == "OUT" when a ticker is removed from the index at date

And I want to add 2 new columns to my main df, with a TRUE for the key (date, ticker), when the couple is found in the second df.

Today I have something like :

```
library(tidyverse)

Ticker = c("DOW","MSCI","BJS")
Action = c("IN","IN","OUT")
Date = c("2019-04-02", "2018-04-04","2010-04-29")

sp500_InOut = data.frame(Ticker, Action, Date)

Ticker = c("DOW", "DOW","MSCI", "MSCI","BJS","BJS")
ref.date = c("2019-04-02", "2018-04-04", "2018-04-04","2010-04-29", "2018-04-04","2010-04-29")
close = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

sp500_OHLC = data.frame(Ticker, ref.date, close)
```

Then in order to update the columns sp500_OHLC$IN and sp500_OHLC$OUT I managed to join like this :

```
#not working
left_join(sp500_OHLC, sp500_InOut, by = c("Ticker" = "Ticker", "ref.date" = "Date"))  
%>% mutate(IN <- ifelse(is.na(Action),FALSE, 
                       ifelse(Action == "IN", TRUE)
%>% mutate(OUT <- ifelse(is.na(Action),FALSE, 
                       ifelse(Action == "OUT", TRUE)
```

But I can't figure out I can now update my columns.

Thanks !!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example that doesn't require us downloading data (e.g. `df = tibble(var_a = c(1,2,3)...)`. BGS isn't importing files for me and it's easier to provide help if you have a clear, short example of what you have *and* what you want (which isn't immediately clear to me).

Comment: Sorry. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution.

```
sp500_OHLC <- sp500_raw %>%  left_join(sp500_InOut, by = c("Ticker" = "Ticker", "ref.date" = "Date"))

sp500_OHLC <- sp500_OHLC %>% mutate(IN = if_else(is.na(Action),FALSE, if_else(Action == "IN", TRUE, FALSE))) 
sp500_OHLC <- sp500_OHLC %>% mutate(OUT = if_else(is.na(Action),FALSE, if_else(Action == "OUT", TRUE, FALSE)))


sp500_OHLC <- sp500_OHLC %>% select(Ticker, ref.date, IN, OUT, close)
```

Comment: I would recommend avoiding overwriting the same tibble repeatedly as a matter of clarity and to avoid bugs when running an interactive session (as R is prone to be used).  While this style was necessary in base R, it doesn't really fit with the tidyverse aesthetic. Since you can continuously pipe in the tidyverse, it's more readable, in my opinion, to execute an entire "thought"/process in a series of pipes, with the purpose of the chunk of code described at the beginning, as you would with a function.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
library(tidyverse)

left_join(
  x = sp500_OHLC,
  y = sp500_InOut %>% 
    mutate(
      IN  = Action == "IN", ##True/False is implicit
      OUT = Action == "OUT"
    ) %>% 
    select(-Action),
  by = c("Ticker", "ref.date" = "Date") ## You don't need to set Ticker equal to itself since it's the same
) %>% 
  #replace_na(list("IN" = FALSE, "OUT" = FALSE)) %>% ## Option 1 (if you care about other NAs being preseved)
  replace(is.na(.), FALSE) ## Option 2 (if these are the only NAs)
```

I generally prefer to avoid `if_else` because, especially when nested, it lends itself to unintentional bugs. Plus if you just replace the NAs after joining with one of the few options dplyr has, it's clearer what you're doing to some other person reading your code and requires less code, both of which are plusses. If you really want to use if/else statements, I would suggest `case_when` which allows you to explicitly specify the conditions and the result of each as it's much clearer than a branching nested `if_else` set.